# Update sequence for verrry old versions of CiviCRM, Wordpress and PHP

Tags: php, upgrade

I'm tasked with updating an old installation of CiviCRM for another org - they have CiviCRM 4.6.3 and WordPress 4.5.18 running on a shared server that's on PHP 5.4.

I don't yet know if it'll be possible to update the server or if the site will need to be transferred to a different server with a more up-to-date version of PHP - in either case, I'm obviously going to need to update incrementally, however, going throught the update announcements, I've found it hard to pin down which version of CiviCRM will still support each older version of PHP and WP.

Before I realised there was a problem with the PHP version, I'd sketched an update process of CiviCRM 4.6.3 -> 4.6.38 -> 4.7.31 -> 5  - what I can't pin down is when in the 4.6/4.7 development PHP 5.4 stopped being supported. I'm hoping there's a 4.7.x release that supported both PHP 5.4 and 7.2, so I can update from 4.6.3 to the concurrent 4.6.x, then to 4.7.x

This post: https://civicrm.org/blog/totten/end-of-zombies-php-53-and-54 indicates support for PHP 5.4 was due to end in March 2018, which suggests the November 2017 security releases ( https://civicrm.org/blog/dev-team/security-release-civicrm-4726-and-4633-monthly-release-4727 ) would be okay with PHP 5.4 and 7.0 - however I can't see where this might be confirmed (searching for version numbers isn't much use). (And I don't know if they'd be okay with 7.2, or if there would be issues with the version of WordPress, which can't be updated until the PHP version is updated)

Comment: While slightly different, and on drupal, I do remember once going from even earlier than 4.6 straight to 5.10 without major issue (using php 7.1 at the time I believe, possibly 7.2). So if you can get a server with php 7, a whopping sample size of 1 says you should be ok going to 5.10 at least first, then the rest. The unknown would be whether there were wordpress-related civi changes that might make a difference.